# How to use PHP as Ajax?

Tags: php

I want to implement the same concept as it is in ajax! like there would be a server, request and response!

But I want to use only PHP! not Ajax!

`Battleserver.php` will act as a server and `battle.php` will be at the client side...!

I can send data from battle.php to battleserver.php by using POST method!

But I don't want to make user know that data is send to battleserver.php...!
It should not appear in the URL!
Even after sending data to the server, it should be displayed as battle.php in the link!

How can I do that! ??

Comment: How exactly are you planning to run `battle.php` on the client side?

Comment: You need to read more about ajax, html, php and how web sites work in general. You can't "implement" ajax in pure php. Apart from that! Stop using exclamation marks! Everywhere! Ok?!!!

Comment: Maybe `Curl` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You want to take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) - it is the jQuery ajax documentation. You can send a post request from battle.php to Battleserver.php, and there will be no reload, and no URL changes.